# Unable to refresh the view once an event is executed backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, listener, render

This is my backbone view:

```
View.ModelUploadView = Backbone.ItemView.extend({
        template : modelUploadTpl,

        events : {
            "click a.js-updadeModel" : "updateModel",
        },

        initialize : function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind('change', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this, "model:update", this.render);
        },

        updateModel : function() {
            this.trigger("model:update", this.model.get("id"));
        },
```

When my event click is executed the model will be updated so i need to render the view with the new value of model.
For this i used the listener `this.listenTo(this, "model:update", this.render);` but it doesn't work. Each time i need to refresh the page manually to get the updated model.
ANy solution???

Comment: @nikoshr sorry it was a typo i've updated the code above

Comment: Do you have a render method?

Comment: No i don't have an explicit one i need to execute the default one

Comment: you still need to declare a render method for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have overloaded your *`render`* function, or reassigned Backbone View's *`el`* elsewhere.

The only thing which you need to remember is that view's events are binded to the concrete `DOM node`. So, if you create a new `DOM node` for your view (e.g. in render function) then you need to call Backbone.View.delegateEvents manually.

Answer (score 0):

There's no default render in Backbone, you have to write render for each view. Then, you should listen to your model changes, like this (inside initialize method of your view):

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

Change event will be triggered every time your model attributes change and your view will be rendered.
Inside your DOM event handlers you don't have to trigger changes events to your model, you can just use this.model.set() to change it's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `render` function something like this.

```
View.ModelUploadView = Backbone.ItemView.extend({
    template : modelUploadTpl,

    events : {
        "click a.js-updadeModel" : "updateModel",
    },

    initialize : function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this, "model:update", this.render);
    },

    updateModel : function() {
        this.trigger("model:update", this.model.get("id"));
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
```